# Ubuntu 14.04 wont recognised Android phone

Tags: android

When I connect my HTC one M8 phone with Android 4 (Kitkat), my Ubuntu 14.04 does not recognise the phone. There is nothing on Nautilus to show that it knows its there. The phone will charge but there is no recognition at all.
I have a dual boot on my Acer laptop and Windows 7 recognises my phone and I can read, write copy paste all files so its not a hardware issue.

Does someone have a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please check in which mode you're connecting phone with Ubuntu from below :

1. Media Transfer Mode(MTP)
2. Mass Storage Mode(MSC)

If it is MTP, change it to MSC. It should work now.